# What makes "paster addcontent" fail for a package created with Zopeskel template "archetype"?

Tags: plone, paster, zopeskel

Here is the situation:

- fresh Plone 4.2 buildout
- a fresh package created using Zopeskel 2.21.1 with template 'archetype'
  and configured in my buildout using mr.developer

Trying to add some content types inside my package fails with:

```
[ajung@dev1 nva.aktionsmittel]$ bin/paster addcontent
Command 'addcontent' not known (you may need to run setup.py egg_info)
```

Running setup.py egg_info did not help.

setup.py contains:

```
setup.py:      paster_plugins=["ZopeSkel"]
```

setup.cfg contains:

```
[zopeskel]
template = archetype
```

What is the magic behind the local commands in order to make "paster addcontent" working?
It worked in other contexts as it should?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*ZopeSkel 2 issues*

You are following a bad tutorial. Please make sure that

- You follow instructions specific here http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getstarted/paste.html#adding-zopeskel-to-your-buildout - paster command must come from buildout
- If you are not following the link above then please give the link to the page whose instructions you are follow and I can burn that page as it contains misleading instructions.
- Make sure that paster you are using comes from buildout (from your command line it doesn't seem to be so).
- Make sure your egg is registered in buildout correctly in `eggs =`
   section
- Make sure your setup.py contains necessary boilerplate http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getstarted/paste.html#how-paster-local-commands-work (note: example is ZopeSkel 3+)

This is the way to make paster aware of your egg and its dependencies correctly and thus local commands can work.

*ZopeSkel 3 issue (seemingly unrelated)*

There was a recent change in ZopeSkel, meaning that you if you use ZopeSkel 3+ you need to be in `src`folder when running the command.

See note here:

https://github.com/collective/templer.plone.localcommands/#executing-local-commands

Answer (score 1):

In order for the paster localcommand to run, it must be called from the same directory that contains the .egg-info directory (or a child directory inside it). If pasterns unable to find the .egg-info directory, it cannot run a local command. Paster uses the location of the .egg-info directory to locate setup.cfg, which is then used to determine if any local command entry points are available.

Check to see that you have an .egg-info directory generated inside your package, and that you are invoking paster from the same location or a child folder.